# Trying to remove a paragraph in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button, arguments, event-listener, removechild

I am doing an assignment where I'm meant to remove a paragraph from the page when a button is clicked. I keep returning an error "Uncaught TypeError: Node.removeChild: Argument 1 is not an object." and it references line 37 in my code.

Line 37:
`divTag.removeChild(divTag.children[allPs.length-1]);`

This is part of a script:

```
btnDelete.addEventListener('click', function(){
      var allPs = document.querySelectorAll('p');
      divTag.removeChild(divTag.children[allPs.length-1]);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to consider is that `divTag.children`, which looks at the children of one element in the DOM, may be considerably shorter than `allPs.length`, which as you've defined it is *all* the p elements in the DOM.  What's probably actually causing the error is that you're looking at an index (`[allPs.length - 1]`) that doesn't exist in the array `divTag.children`.  I don't know the exact spec of what you're working on, but you can try replacing `divTag.children[allPs.length - 1]` with `allPs[allPs.length - 1]`.  Without more info on what the actual spec is that's about as helpful as I can be for now. If you have more info I can elaborate in a comment.

Comment: Thank you. This makes more sense to me than anything. It's no longer throwing an error but alas won't work. I'm going to re-review the material and see what I can do. But you helped me get rid of the error and that is a huge step so thank you!